# How can I create a loop that runs two functions, never overlapping?

Tags: swift, function, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm new to programming and have been taking online courses in swift and spritekit trying to create my first working game from scratch.

Currently I'm having an issue trying to create a sequence of functions that run independently, wait so that only one is running at a time, and loops indefinitely.

The first function:

```
func shootTwentyArrows() {

    var oneArrow = SKAction.runBlock{

        self.shootArrow()

    }

    var waitBetweenArrows = SKAction.waitForDuration(arrowSpeed)
    var fireAnArrow = SKAction.sequence([oneArrow, waitBetweenArrows])
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(fireAnArrow, count: 20))
}
```

And the second function:

```
func shootSpiral1() {

    var leftArrow = SKAction.runBlock{

        self.arrowFromLeft()

    }

    var rightArrow = SKAction.runBlock{

        self.arrowFromRight()

    }

    var waitBetweenArrows = SKAction.waitForDuration(arrowSpeed)
    var sequence = SKAction.sequence([leftArrow, waitBetweenArrows, rightArrow, waitBetweenArrows])

    var spiral1 = SKAction.repeatAction(sequence, count: 5)

    self.runAction(spiral1)
```

to clarify, I'm trying to run something like:
shootTwentyArrows()
when that's done, shootSpiral1(), when that's done repeat.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: do you treat function as completed when it actually completes or when actions that created inside are done?

Comment: when the actions in the function have been completed

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most correct way to do that would be to refactor code a little bit:

```
func shootTwentyArrows() -> SKAction {

let oneArrow = SKAction.runBlock{

    self.shootArrow()

}

let waitBetweenArrows = SKAction.waitForDuration(arrowSpeed)
let fireAnArrow = SKAction.sequence([oneArrow, waitBetweenArrows])
return SKAction.repeatAction(fireAnArrow, count: 20)
}

func shootSpiral1() -> SKAction {

let leftArrow = SKAction.runBlock{

    self.arrowFromLeft()

}

let rightArrow = SKAction.runBlock{

    self.arrowFromRight()

}

let waitBetweenArrows = SKAction.waitForDuration(arrowSpeed)
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([leftArrow, waitBetweenArrows, rightArrow, waitBetweenArrows])

let spiral1 = SKAction.repeatAction(sequence, count: 5)
return spiral1
}
```

Then somewhere in the code you can just do something like that :

```
let spiralAction = shootSpiral1()
let oneArrowAction = shootTwentyArrows()
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spiralAction, oneArrowAction])
let infiniteSequence = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence)
self.runAction(infiniteSequence)
```

I left function names the same on purpose, so you get the idea.

**P.S.** It is a common practice to declare a variable as `let`, declare it as `var` only when you have to modify it later.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I haven't yet tried this (I will be momentarily) but I'm wondering if you can explain to me what about this code will make the sequence not run the two functions simultaneously?

Comment: @Casey, if that worked for you, you should mark the answer as correct (the tick on the left hand side) :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is have an SKAction sequence that calls both of your functions. You would call this SKAction from wherever you want to initialize the arrow shooting actions like `viewDidLoad` for example. This would be the code to call the actions...

```
var actionShootingArrows = SKAction.sequence([shootSpiral1(), shootTwentyArrows()])
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(actionShootingArrows))
```

Hope this helps!